# How to create a button with an image and a text side by side over the button?

Tags: java, android, xml

What i want is an android button which has both an image and a text inside it.
I dont want the image to be the background and text over it, instead , what i am looking for is the image and the text to come side by side, next to each other.
How to achieve that in xml or java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is through xml. You can set compound drawables on a `TextView` with a field such as [drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft). `drawableRight`, `drawableBottom`, and `drawableTop` are also available.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sample_image"
    android:text="@string/sample_text"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>
```

Or the same thing can be accomplished programmatically with the [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method. In the case below the left drawable is being set to the R.drawable.icon resource.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```